# Centralize connection strings for multiple projects within the same solution

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config

I currently have three projects in my solution that all have their own App.config file with the same exact connection string.

Is there a way to consolidate the connections strings / app.config files so that I only need to make changes to one location?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share a Connection string between multiple web projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660502/share-a-connection-string-between-multiple-web-projects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few ways you could do it:

1. Put common configuration settings in machine.config as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697.aspx)
2. Put common configuration settings in a central file and link to that in each projects's app.config as shown [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/555396)
3. Store the configuration settings in the registry

For me, i always work with the last solution :)
Good luck!

Comment: The second option seems to be the most desirable, but the link is broken.  Can you please fix it?

Comment: @DelLee i just fixed the link ;)

Comment: The link is broken again. Can you fix this, please?

Comment: You shouldn't link to other pages without also adding the info to SO. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/769294

Answer (score 25):

You can share the connection strings among multiple projects in a solution as follows:

1. Create a `ConnectionStrings.config` file with your connection strings under a solution folder, this file should contain only the section `connectionStrings`
2. In your projects, add this config file As a Link (add existing item, add as link)
3. Select the added file and set its property `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`
4. In the `App.config` of your projects, point to the linked `ConnectionStrings.config` file using the `configSource` attribute:
   `<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config" />`

**ConnectionStrings.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    ...
    <connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config" />
    ...
</configuration>
```

[Read more details...](https://salimbenhadou.wordpress.com/2016/11/06/centralize-and-share-connection-strings-among-multiple-projects/).

Comment: You can't figure it out until you give it a try ;) don't wait for others to test code for you.

Comment: Great answer, you may need to add 'bin\' prefix if are you copying to output directory. <connectionStrings configSource="bin\ConnectionStrings.config" />

Comment: And what if I need two separate connection strings for debug and release (like Web.Debug.config and Web.Debug.Release)?

Comment: Very good way to handle this. Thanks, @Stacked. I've got a question similar to the one from JohnB's: can you perform transformations on this shared configuration file?

Comment: Much better than just linking to 404 pages with no context or discussion. Works great!

Comment: @JohnB I guess you would have ConnectionStrings.Debug.config and ConnectionStrings.Release.config that you would link to in each of your projects and reference in the Web.Debug.config or Web.Release.config or App.Debug.config or App.Release.config.  It's a lot of file duplication though :/

Comment: When you add the config file as a link, and your project file(s) include(s) settings, you will get an error in Visual Studio stating that it could not properly read the project's XML file. So I didn't add the file as a link but did a regular add and set up a pre-build command line event to copy the ConnectionString.config from the master location into the individual project(s)

Answer (score 3):

First, take a look at this post. It describes how you can share the same app.config between multiple projects.

[How to Share App.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426245/how-to-share-app-config)

Second, take a look at one other post, which describes how you let different app.config-files have a reference to one single shared xml-file which contains the connection strings.

[Use XML includes or config references in app.config to include other config files' settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480538/use-xml-includes-or-config-references-in-app-config-to-include-other-config-file)