# common web.config connectionstrings for different web applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web.config-transform

We have multiple web applications and deploy all web applications in same folder called iapps. But each app has its own web.config file and must most of the have commmon connection strings.

Now I want to make a common configuration file which all the application read the connection strings and use it. How can we do that? Any good articles or examples

### Current

```
\iapps\app1
         |- web.config

\iapps\app2
         |- web.config

\iapps\app3
         |- web.config
```

Expecting

```
\iapps\app1    --Web.cofig
    |-root Config <-|
\iapps\app2    --Web.cofig
    |-root Config  <-|   
\iapps\app3    --Web.cofig
    |-root Config  <-|
```

Comment: whats wrong with using one config file and adding multiple connection nodes..? this is totally possible.. we do it on a daily basis .. I think that personally it's harder to maintain 3 separate .config files but I guess anything is possible as well

Comment: You could put the connection strings in the machine.config

Comment: set names for each application. <connectionStrings>
    <add name="app1" connectionString="..."

Comment: Are they under one solution or multiple solutions?

Comment: multiple solutions, Is there anyway to read xml from web.config file?

Comment: If they are multiple solutions, then I would suggest to **NOT** have a common config file. The cons outweigh the pros. Adding them to machine.config would probably work but somehow I don't like the sound of that. If all the apps share the same root folder, then you can define the connection string in the root's web.config. That way child apps will derive from the root and will see them automatically. You then have to ensure that child app's web.config doesn't contain those connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1660534/244353) already describes several alternatives. In addition, you can also leverage the idea of inheritance by placing all common connection strings in `web.config` under root (i.e. iApps in this case).

app1...appN will all inherit settings from `iapps\web.config`

Just be careful that anythinn you define in `iapps\web.config` doesn't get redefined in child apps' web.config, else you'll get duplicate section defined error in your child apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the configuration in your AppDomain object.

Your web.config could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="WebApp1" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
<section name="WebApp2" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</configSections>
<WebApp1>
   <add key="Key1" value="App1 value"/>
</WebApp1>
<WebApp2>
   <add key="Key1" value="App2 value"/>
</WebApp2>
</configuration>
```

And in your PageLoad event you could use this:

```
SetConfig();
var webApp1Config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("WebApp1") as NameValueCollection;
var webApp2Config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("WebApp2") as NameValueCollection;

private static void SetConfig()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", @"C:\Temp\web.config");
    var fieldInfo = typeof(ConfigurationManager).GetField("s_initState", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    if (fieldInfo != null)
        fieldInfo.SetValue(null, 0);
    var field = typeof(ConfigurationManager).GetField("s_configSystem", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    if (field != null)
        field.SetValue(null, null);
    var info = typeof(ConfigurationManager).Assembly.GetTypes().First(x => x.FullName == "System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths").GetField("s_current", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    if (info != null)
        info.SetValue(null, null);
}
```

Now you can read your settings from the configuration settings:

```
var key1Value = webApp1Config["Key1"];
```

Cheers Martin