# How to share app.config SQL Connection String between projects

Tags: c#, connection-string, system.io.fileinfo

I have a set of projects (e.g., For DataProvider, Tests and Main).

I'm getting a SQL connection string from my `app.config` file using ConfigManager.

When I need to use this connection string in project other than Main, currently I need to copy-n-paste the connection string to next `app.config`.

Can I configure it so that all projects read the connection string from the main `app.config` file?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660502/share-a-connection-string-between-multiple-web-projects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [single app.config multi-project c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361913/single-app-config-multi-project-c-sharp)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487991/is-there-any-way-for-an-app-config-file-to-reference-another-full-config-file